# unsort Hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

i am writing a program in C#
i have a code like this

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            ht.Add("1", "One");
            ht.Add("2", "Two");
            ht.Add("3", "Three");
            ht.Add("4", "Four");
```

but Compiler sort it
i wanna know how can i prevent sorting hashtable
please help me

Answer (score 6):

A `HashTable` doesn't do sorting as such. It does rearrange the items based on their hash code, so the original order isn't preserved.

If you want to preserve the original order, or want to specify a sort order, you can't use a `HashTable` only.

To specify a different sort order, you can use a `SortedDictionary<T>`. To preserve the original order, you can add the items both to a `Dictionary<T>` and a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the compiler sorting it? There is definitely NO sorting done. How are you looping over the items?

I think that order of items when you loop over the keys isn't guaranteed ->

```
foreach(object key in hashtable.Keys){
...
}
```

but from your question I think you'd like to retrieve the items in the exact same order as you have inserted them - maybe the best solution would be to keep parallel List of your keys; and retrieve keys for looping over hashtable from there.

Comment: hi
i wanna show it like when i add it to hashtable 
like this ===> one two three frour 
but its not like this

Comment: @user222820: If you want a data structure which preserves insertion order, then don't use Hashtable - it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dictionary<int, string>` or `Dictionary <string, string>` instead.

Comment: The `Dictionary<>` class is the typed equivalent to the `HashTable` class so that is preferred, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When doing:

```
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add("1", "One");
        ht.Add("2", "Two");
        ht.Add("3", "Three");
        ht.Add("4", "Four");

        foreach (var k in ht.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k);
        }
```

I see no sorting of any kind taking place.

Comment: its not sort . but is it same order that i inserted?

Comment: The order I get is 4, 1, 2, 3. Perhaps Hashtable stores its data by hashvalue (hence the name)?

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables do not preserve the order of inserted items.  They are stored in a data structure that has no concept of a "correct" order.  You should assume that items in a hashtable will be stored in a random order.

You should use a List or other structure instead of a Hashtable if the order of the items is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.Add("1", "One");
    ht.Add("2", "Two");
    ht.Add("3", "Three");
    ht.Add("4", "Four");

    foreach (var k in ht.Keys.sort)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(k);
    }
```

Notice the `sort` after `ht.Keys`

Comment: That results in: Error 1 'System.Collections.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'sort' and no extension method 'sort' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) - Did you even test it before posting?

Comment: Please check the date on which this answer was written. I don't remember.

Comment: Regardless of the date you posted, that's the result one get's by trying that code - for the sake of future visitors to this page it should be said it doesn't work - or at least not anymore. Would be nice if you had put some warning like 'this works only with .net x' but since you didn't i left a warning for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

To get the Values in your hashtable ordered by key (wich is what it looks like you want) use this:

```
public List<string> GetOrderedValues(HashTable ht)
{
    // Get a sorted list of keys
    List<string> keys = new List<string>(ht.Keys.Cast<string>());
    keys.Sort();

    // Get values sorted by key
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    foreach (string key in keys)
        values.Add(ht[key]);

    // Return Sorted Values
    return values;
}
```

You can also separete the first part and then you can get both a list of sorted keys and a list of sorted values.

Another option is return a List of KeyValuePair wichh will be sorted by entry

Then again, why not just remove all the ashle and replace your hashtable with a List of KeyValuePair in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog, http://mctexpert.blogspot.com/2014/12/keeping-hash-table-in-order.html

To be specific, using `[Ordered]` would help with keeping the original sort:

```
$Hash = [Ordered]@{"Apple"="Red";

"Orange"="Orange";

"Banana"="Yellow";

"Pear"="Green";

"Blueberry"="Blue";

"Plum"="Purple"}
```